# Can a batch file capture the exit codes of the commands it is invoking?

Tags: batch-file, exit-code

Basically, let's say that I have a batch file that calls myapp1.exe and myapp1.exe exits with Exit Code 1. Can the batch file capture this information and either force the batch file to exit with that same exit code or perform some other logic?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
@echo off
rem ...
set errorlevel=
MyApp1.exe
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

would be the explicit variant.

Comment: thnx, until powershell can return negative exit codes I'm forced to continue wrapping my powershell scripts w/ batch scripts~

Comment: It appears that at least PowerShell v3 can return negative exit codes: `powershell 'exit -5'; $LASTEXITCODE` yields `-5` for me.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you are using `call` to call another batch script, and that second batch script is using `SetLocal`, you may need to use a parsing trick to accomplish this. If you are running into this, add the following code before your `exit b`:

```
ENDLOCAL&set myvariable=%myvariable%
```

Now the value of `myvariable` is made available to the calling context and you can see the value in the other script.

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16167938/89590
http://www.borngeek.com/2008/05/22/exiting-batch-file-contexts/

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [`errorlevel`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php)s. Some more info [here](http://www.eacsystems.com/misc/batch/batchcommands.htm).

Comment: Do, or do not. There is no "try". (And in this case, if you do use the errorlevel, it will work ;)

Answer (score 4):

%ERRORLEVEL% stores the return value of last executed command

```
call program.exe
echo program.exe returns "%ERRORLEVEL%"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo FAILED
)
```

Comment: This is already stated by the accepted answer from years ago, seems to me.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy I'm not sure it's explicitly stated by the accepted answer. Certainly I found this answer more useful. (I am very unfamiliar with batch scripts)