# capturing error message from echo in cmd prompt

Tags: cmd

I'm writting out some text to a text file within a cmd batch script like such:

```
echo FlagValue=Y>>flag.txt
```

This normally works fine but occassionally if the text file is open by a different process, an error messgae is returned saying Access Denied. What I'd like to do is stop the batch file if an error occurs with something like:

```
if return_code GEQ 1 GOTO ERR
```

But can't find a return code from echo command. Does one exist, or is there a better tactic to use to capture error message?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo FlagValue=Y>>flag.txt || echo access_denied Ensure you have rights
```

or

```
echo FlagValue=Y>>flag.txt
if /i %errorlevel% NEQ 0 do (
  echo access_denied Ensure you have rights
  call sendmail.cmd
)
```

Sample:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop>echo Hello > MyFile.txt || echo ERROR
Access is denied.
ERROR

C:\Users\Me\Desktop>echo Hello > a.txt || echo ERROR

C:\Users\Me\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you run a command the ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to your command's return. So try echo %ERRORLEVEL% straight after you run your command. (Be careful as any command you run inbetween (including echo) will override the %ERRORLEVEL%.

Also, check these out for more information:
[Can a batch file capture the exit codes of the commands it is invoking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680977/can-a-batch-file-capture-the-exit-codes-of-the-commands-it-is-invoking)
[Batch Files - Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164049/batch-files-error-handling)

Comment: I tried building a little test script 

echo off
echo testline>>file1.txt
echo errorlevel=%ERRORLEVEL%

but result I got back was 

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
errorlevel=0

Comment: what error level do you get when you **can** access the file? i.e try to write to another file file2.txt

Comment: I still get errorlevel=0 regardless whether I can write to the file or not